# ocsps are not shown but I have in DSS

Tags: pdf, digital-signature, pdfbox, adobe-reader

I've just sign document. and Add LTV too (with Document Secure Story and TSA); but adobe reader tells me that LTV is not enabled.

I found the problem. Adobe reader tells me that OCSP is not embedded in the document.

After adding time stamp I just create DSS dictionary and add certificates and ocsp responses.

```
        PDDocumentCatalog catalog = template.getDocumentCatalog();
        COSDictionary catalogDictionary = catalog.getCOSDictionary();
        COSDictionary dssDictionary = new COSDictionary();

        COSArray cosOcsps = CertUtils.getOcspResponseCosArray(ocspResp);
        COSArray cosCerts = CertUtils.getCertificateCosArray(certs);

        dssDictionary.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("Certs"), cosCerts);
        dssDictionary.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("OCSPs"), cosOcsps);
        catalogDictionary.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("DSS"), dssDictionary);
```

is not that enough to add OCSPs?

[image]

I sign document like Pades-BES. does it needs VRI? I know that id does not need.

that's sample

[PDF Document](http://www.dropbox.com/s/4m1zgntnbetx283/LTV.pdf)

Comment: I've just add CRLs to DSS and they are shown. but not OCSP responses. (they are not embedded)

Comment: Is this a new trend? Adding 'iText' as a tag when asking questions about PDFBox?

Comment: Lowagie - first of all I respect your knowledge and you too. no Its question to Itext developers too, because they have big knowledge and they already have created everything in digital signature. I'm sorry if my tag was incorrect. :-)

Comment: Suppose that you've bought a car A in garage B and you get a warranty on that car. Suppose that your car breaks down after one month. It's obvious that you can't go to a dealer of car X in garage Y to get your car fixed for free, isn't it? That's whay you've been doing: you are using PDFBox (ASL) instead of iText (AGPL / Commercial), but you're expecting that iText people help you out while you're using a competing product.

Comment: you are right :-) p.s I have already done that thing in itext. I use pdfbox for learning (its more deep level). I like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification [ETSI TS 102 778-4](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/102700_102799/10277804/01.01.02_60/ts_10277804v010102p.pdf) (aka PAdES part 4) in Annex A.1 *Document Security Store* requires the value of the **OCSPs** entry in a **DSS** dictionary to be

> An array of (indirect references to) streams, each containing a BER-encoded Online Certificate Status Protocol (OCSP) response (see RFC 2560 [8]). This array contains OCSPs that may be used in the validation of any signatures in the document.

You, on the other hand, only used an array of the `BasicOCSPResponse` objects which were *contained* in the original `OCSPResponse` objects you received.

```
OCSPResponse ::= SEQUENCE {
  responseStatus OCSPResponseStatus,
  responseBytes  [0] EXPLICIT ResponseBytes OPTIONAL }

ResponseBytes ::= SEQUENCE {
   responseType   OBJECT IDENTIFIER,
   response       OCTET STRING }

For a basic OCSP responder, responseType will be id-pkix-ocsp-basic.

The value for response SHALL be the DER encoding of BasicOCSPResponse.

BasicOCSPResponse ::= SEQUENCE {
  tbsResponseData     ResponseData,
  signatureAlgorithm  AlgorithmIdentifier,
  signature           BIT STRING,
  certs               [0] EXPLICIT SEQUENCE OF Certificate OPTIONAL }
```

> *(from section 4.2.1 ASN.1 Specification of the OCSP Response of [RFC 2560](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2560.txt))*

Probably you were not aware that you only used this inner object because many security libraries after requesting an OCSP response unwrap the original `OCSPResponse,` check the contained `OCSPResponseStatus,` and (if it indicates success) only return the contained `BasicOCSPResponse` or (otherwise) throw some exception.

If that's the case, you can simply wrap your `BasicOCSPResponse` in an `OCSPResponse` using the `OCSPResponseStatus` value `successful (0)` before putting it into the document.